# The client-side JavaScript app (Next.js) breaks unexpectedly, without any console errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server, next.js

I have a server that assembles HTML from JSON response:

```
{
  content: "<div id=\"_next\">...</div>...<script src=\"...\"></script>"
}
```

Node server:

```
const output = "<html>..." + data.content;
return res.send(output);
```

*Note: I've omitted a lot of the code here for brevity.*

The above setup sends the HTML to the browser, with no issues, however, as soon as JavaScript loads, the DOM breaks, as if there's a React error, with no console output of any sort.

I ran a test where the Node creates output without fetching JSON data, by simply copy-pasting the HTML content:

```
const output = "<html>..." + "<div id=\"_next\">...</div>...<script src=\"...\"></script>";
return res.send(output);
```

...In which case, there are no JS errors and everything renders as-expected.

---

I've compared the HTML responses, they seem identical. The async nature of fetching JSON doesn't seem to be an issue either. The problem also seems to be cross-environmental as the original back-end system meant to use this code is written in Java and it produces identical result (DOM breaking with no console output).

Comment: no stacktraces? That sounds strange

Comment: Sorry for the self-closing script tags. I'll edit the code to be more valid.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is somewhat incomplete because I don't know why or how the solution works:

**To fix the issue, the filename within the URL must match the rendered static file's.**

For example, if the static file exported by Next.js app reads `file-name.html` and is served locally as `http://localhost:5000/out/file-name`, the end-url that serves the HTML has to also contain `file-name`, like this: `http://localhost:3000/another-url-structure/file-name`. If it doesn't, i.e.: `http://localhost:3000/random-string`, the DOM will break.

Clear as mud but that's the only solution for the issue right now.